# Join elements that are not in group

Tags: sqlite

I have a database whose layout is out of my control, which contains two entities, "Person" and "Trait". Each person may have multiple traits and each trait may be associated to multiple persons. There's an intermediate entity for this relationship:

[image: Person <->> Person_Trait <<-> Trait]

So far so good. I want to create a list with all the traits, the persons who do have a given trait, and the persons who do **not** have that same trait. The positives are simple:

```
SELECT t.id,
   t.name,
   positives.count,
   positives.members
FROM Trait t
   JOIN (
       SELECT t.id,
              count() AS count,
              group_concat(p.name) AS members
         FROM Person p
              JOIN Person_Trait pt ON pt.id_person = p.Id
              JOIN Trait t ON t.id = p.id_trait
        GROUP BY t.id
   )
   AS positives ON t.id = positives.id;
```

However I'm stumped on how to get the negative group such that I can join against it. Any ideas?

I can make views, if those might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to find the negative group by:

1. getting the cross-product of p.id and t.id from person and trait (all possible combinations of persons and traits)
2. subtracting the set of positives from the cross-product

what remains is the set of all p.id/t.id pairs that are negatives

Then you can perform a query similar to what you have.

So the query to get the complete set of negatives would be:

```
SELECT p.id AS p_id, t.id AS t_id
FROM person p, trait t
EXCEPT
SELECT pt.id_person, pt.id_trait
FROM person_trait pt
```

Then you can slide this in as a subquery JOINed to the other tables, to get names:

```
SELECT q1.t_id, t.name, COUNT() AS negcount, GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) AS negmem
FROM 
    (SELECT p.id AS p_id, t.id AS t_id
        FROM person p, trait t
     EXCEPT
     SELECT pt.id_person, pt.id_trait
        FROM person_trait pt) q1
JOIN trait t ON t.id = q1.t_id
JOIN person p ON p.id = q1.p_id
GROUP BY t_id
```

This works for me with trial data. Then you can set up combining this query with your existing positives query.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks a lot. It was actually more obvious that I'd expected, but I wasn't aware of EXCEPT.